# extract rows max value groupby another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

If I have a data frame looking like the following, and I want the max value of "f0max" from the file that has the same name.

```
  f0max file maxtime
0   9   1   1
1   8   1   2
2   7   1   3
3   6   2   4
4   5   2   5
5   4   2   6
6   3   3   7
7   2   3   8
8   1   3   9
```

so the result would be

```
  f0max file maxtime
0   9   1   1
3   6   2   4
6   3   3   7
```

so the result would be (in real data there is no same value for f0max and maxtime)

is this possible in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

To return the entire row corresponding to the max f0max within each file

```
df.sort_values('f0max').groupby('file').tail(1)
```

#### Output:

```
   f0max  file  maxtime
6      3     3        7
3      6     2        4
0      9     1        1
```

Comment: Succinct and functional

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean indexing with `GroupBy` + `transform`. Note this will *include* duplicate maxima by group.

```
df = df[df['f0max'] == df.groupby('file')['f0max'].transform('max')]
```

Or you can sort and then drop duplicates by your grouper. If duplicate maxima exist by group, only one will be kept:

```
df = df.sort_values('f0max', ascending=False)\
       .drop_duplicates('file')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   f0max  file  maxtime
0      9     1        1
3      6     2        4
6      3     3        7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1 = df.merge(df.groupby('file', as_index=False)['f0max'].max())
print (df1)

   file  f0max  maxtime
0   1     9       1
1   2     6       4
2   3     3       7
```

Comment: for the 'maxtime':'first' => how can I have the value of the original  'maxtime' of  the 'f0max' ? the df above happens to have the first value of maxtime for "maxtime" but what I wanted was the "maxtime" that belongs to the "f0max". So no change in "maxtime" ... I hope my explnation is clear.